# Subset a list of dict by keeping a maximum of duplicates

Tags: python-2.7

I've to subset a list of dict with conditions on duplicates keys.
For instance with `max_duplicates = 2` on key 'main' and the following list:

```
[
 {'main': 1, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 1, 'more': 2},
 {'main': 1, 'more': 3},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 3},
 {'main': 3, 'more': 1}
]
```

I would like to get:

```
[
 {'main': 1, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 1, 'more': 2},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 3, 'more': 1}
]
```

The selected elements for a given key can be random, and the key will be always the same.

I am looking for the best optimized solution. For now this is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy


def remove_duplicates(initial_list, max_duplicates):
    main_counts = Counter([elem["main"] for elem in initial_list])
    main_values_for_selection = set([main_value for main_value, count in main_counts.iteritems()
                                     if count > max_duplicates])
    result = [elem for elem in initial_list
              if elem["main"] not in main_values_for_selection]

    for main_value in main_values_for_selection:
        all_indexes = [index for index, elem in enumerate(initial_list)
                       if elem["main"] == main_value]
        indexes = numpy.random.choice(a=all_indexes, size=max_duplicates, replace=False)
        result += [initial_list[i] for i in indexes]
    return result
```

Thanks in advance for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method always takes the first 2 or `max_duplicate` of a given key that it sees, but I think it is pretty efficient, only looking through the list once with few temporary variables:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def remove_duplicates(initials,max_dups):
    dup_tracker = defaultdict(int)
    rets = []
    for entry in initials:
        if dup_tracker[entry['main']] < max_dups:
            dup_tracker[entry['main']] += 1
            rets.append(entry)
    return rets

max_dups = 2
initials = [
 {'main': 1, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 1, 'more': 2},
 {'main': 1, 'more': 3},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 1},
 {'main': 2, 'more': 3},
 {'main': 3, 'more': 1}
]


rets = remove_duplicates(initials,max_dups)        
print rets
```

To explain the code, `defaultdict(int)` creates a dictionary where every key (even if it is not yet defined), starts off with a value of 0. Next we loop through the list and keep track of how many of each key we've seen in the `dup_tracker` which is a dict keyed by the values of `'main'` and valued by the number of times its seen that specific key. If the `dup_tracker` has seen few enough entries with that given key, it appends it to the `rets` output array and then returns it.

TIMED EDIT:
It looks like the method I implemented is at least a couple of orders of magnitude faster than yours. I included all the code I used to time them below.

TL;DR `Yours 35.721 seconds` vs `mine 0.016 seconds` when running on a list of 50,000 dicts, with values of `main` ranging from 0-10,000

```
from collections import Counter
import random
import time
​
def remove_duplicates_1(initial_list, max_duplicates):
    main_counts = Counter([elem["main"] for elem in initial_list])
    main_values_for_selection = set([main_value for main_value, count in main_counts.iteritems()
                                     if count > max_duplicates])
    result = [elem for elem in initial_list
              if elem["main"] not in main_values_for_selection]
​
    for main_value in main_values_for_selection:
        all_indexes = [index for index, elem in enumerate(initial_list)
                       if elem["main"] == main_value]
        indexes = numpy.random.choice(a=all_indexes, size=max_duplicates, replace=False)
        result += [initial_list[i] for i in indexes]
    return result
​
​
def remove_duplicates_2(initials,max_dups):
    dup_tracker = {}
    rets = []
    for entry in initials:
        if entry['main'] not in dup_tracker:
            dup_tracker[entry['main']] = 1
            rets.append(entry)
        elif dup_tracker[entry['main']] < max_dups:
            dup_tracker[entry['main']] += 1
            rets.append(entry)
    return rets
​
def generate_test_list(num_total,max_main):
    test_list = []
    for it in range(num_total):
        main_value = round(random.random()*max_main)
        test_list.append({'main':main_value, 'more':it})
    return test_list
​
max_duplicates = 2
test_list = generate_test_list(50000,10000)
​
start = time.time()
rets_1 = remove_duplicates_1(test_list,max_duplicates)
time_1 = time.time()-start
​
start = time.time()
rets_2 = remove_duplicates_2(test_list,max_duplicates)
time_2 = time.time()-start
​
print "Yours",time_1,"vs mine",time_2

#Results:
#Yours 35.7210621834 vs mine 0.0159771442413
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rbierman ! I'm not using to use `defaultdict`, but it's quite easy to understand. In your solution you iterate over all `dict` in the list whereas in my function I iterate only over duplicates `dict` thanks to the counter. Would you say that a quicker solution would be to combine my function with yours ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on behind the scenes in `Counter`, but you have to imagine it's going through all lists in the original `dict` to count how many are of each, so I think your code is doing that work just like mine, but then doing additional work to go through each of the duplicate `dict`. I'm arguing my code is faster but I'll run some speed tests later today if I have time to check it out

Comment: Also, I didn't using defaultdict above and it's not a large change to the code at all

Comment: Ok super ! I'm very surprised of the time saved :-) I will definitely use your solution !